# How to solve the WordPress install complete

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, wordpress

I have this error:

```
chown: missing operand after 'www-data:www-data/var/www/'
```

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/566421) Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting). This goes double when you're asking for help on a script. Surely you don't expect us to copy that line by line in order to try to run it and identify the problems!

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing white space in your command. Probably you want to:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

In your case, the `chown` command will search for a group called `www-data/var/www/` (that is threat as single string), and complains about a missing argument - the target path.